# Sign of the maximum absolute value in an __m128, SSE4

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I need to know the sign of the value which has the max absolute value stored in an __m128. This is the solution I have now:

```
int getMaxSign(__m128 const& vec) {
    static const __m128 SIGN_BIT_MASK = 
      _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_set1_epi32(0x80000000));

    // This creates an int, where sign(a) is 1 if a is negative, 0 o.w.:
    // sign(a3)<<3 | sign(a2)<<2 | sign(a1)<<1 | sign(a0)
    const int signMask = _mm_movemask_ps(vec);

    // Get the absolute value of the vector;
    __m128 absValsMMX = _mm_andnot_ps(SIGN_BIT_MASK, vec);

    // Figure out the horizontal max
    __declspec(align(16)) float absVals[4];
    _mm_store_ps(absVals, absValsMMX);

    const float maxVal = std::max(std::max(absVals[0], absVals[1]), absVals[2]);

    return (maxVal == absVals[0] ? signMask & 0x1 : 
      (maxVal == absVals[1] ? signMask & 0x2 : signMask & 0x4));
}
```

In this case, sign will be 1 if the value with the maximum absolute value was negative, and 0 otherwise, but I don't actually care what the convention is. Another thing is that I am representing homogenous vectors using these __m128s, so I know that the last value will always be 0.

This seems like a lot of work to do for a relatively simple task. How can I do this faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify whether you want the sign of the max value or the sign of the value which has the max absolute value ?

Comment: You're right, that was really unclear. I edited the question to clarify. For the sake of redundancy, I want the sign of the value which has the max absolute value.

Comment: Is it OK to use SSSE3 ? SSE4 ?

Comment: Any of the SSE instructions are fine, including SSE4 and SSE3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation (in C):

```
int getMaxSign(const __m128 v)
{
    __m128 v1, vmax, vmin, vsign;
    float sign;

    v1 = (__m128)_mm_alignr_epi8((__m128i)v, (__m128i)v, 4); // v1 = v rotated by 1 element
    vmax = _mm_max_ps(v, v1);           // generate horizontal max/min
    vmin = _mm_min_ps(v, v1);
    vmax = _mm_max_ps(vmax, (__m128)_mm_alignr_epi8((__m128i)vmax, (__m128i)vmax, 8));
    vmin = _mm_min_ps(vmin, (__m128)_mm_alignr_epi8((__m128i)vmin, (__m128i)vmin, 8));
    vsign = _mm_add_ps(vmax, vmin);     // add max and min to get sign of abs max
    sign = _mm_extract_ps(vsign, 0);
    return (int)(sign < 0.0f);          // return 1 for negative
}
```

Although this looks like a lot of code it's only about 9 SSE instructions and there are no memory accesses, no branches and very little scalar code.

Note that both SSSE3 and SSE4.1 instructions are used in the above.

Here is a second version which only requires SSSE3:

```
int getMaxSign(const __m128 v)
{
    __m128 v1, vmax, vmin, vsign;
    int mask;

    v1 = (__m128)_mm_alignr_epi8((__m128i)v, (__m128i)v, 4); // v1 = v rotated by 1 element
    vmax = _mm_max_ps(v, v1);           // generate horizontal max/min
    vmin = _mm_min_ps(v, v1);
    vmax = _mm_max_ps(vmax, (__m128)_mm_alignr_epi8((__m128i)vmax, (__m128i)vmax, 8));
    vmin = _mm_min_ps(vmin, (__m128)_mm_alignr_epi8((__m128i)vmin, (__m128i)vmin, 8));
    vsign = _mm_add_ps(vmax, vmin);     // add max and min to get sign of abs max
    mask = _mm_movemask_epi8((__m128i)vsign);
    return (mask & 8) != 0;             // return 1 for negative
}
```

This generates 12 instructions:

```
pshufd  $57, %xmm0, %xmm1
movdqa  %xmm0, %xmm2
minps   %xmm1, %xmm2
pshufd  $78, %xmm2, %xmm3
minps   %xmm3, %xmm2
maxps   %xmm1, %xmm0
pshufd  $78, %xmm0, %xmm1
maxps   %xmm1, %xmm0
addps   %xmm2, %xmm0
pmovmskb    %xmm0, %eax
shrl    $3, %eax
andl    $1, %eax
```

Note how the compiler craftily changes `palignr` to `pshufd` and also implements the final scalar test using just a `shrl` and an `andl`.

---

Note for Visual Studio C/C++: to cast between `__m128` and `__m128i` you'll need to use `_mm_castps_si128` and `_mm_castsi128_ps`, e.g.

```
    mask = _mm_movemask_epi8((__m128i)vsign);
```

would need to be changed to:

```
    mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(vsign));
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, though: my compiler (VS10) is telling me that it can't cast between __m128 and __m128i. Is this because I'm using a C++ compiler?

Comment: No - it's because you're using Visual Studio unfortunately, which is just about the worst compiler possible for SSE coding. You'll need to do the casts a little differently - I've added a footnote to the answer now to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = min(a,b,c);  
M = max(a,b,c);  

// return abs(m)>abs(M) ? sign(m): sign(M);   // was
return sign(m+M);
```

As correctly noticed by Paul_R, the sign comes simply from the sum of the min and max values. Which ever has larger (opposite signed) absolute value, wins.

But the idea can be exploited more: the sum of min/max is the same, as the sum of all the elements, minus the middle one, which can be found by max 3 comparisons.

```
return sign(a+b+c - middle(a,b,c));  // or
return sign(a*aw + b*bw + c*cw);     // where aw,bw,cw = [0,1]
```

aw,bw,cw could be derived from the number of won comparisons (which I think have to planned carefully for the case, when there are 2 or 3 equal values.)

And further:

```
x = abs(b)>abs(a)?b:a;
return sign(x+c);
```

Possibly even further:

```
s = sign(a + b);  // store the sign of larger of a or b  
a = abs(a); b=abs(b);  
a = max(a,b) | s;   // somehow copy the sign.  
return sign(a+c);
```

Comment: So you suggest that there is no advantage to having the vector come in as an SSE intrinsic, and that the best option is to store all the values in a float[4], and do the computation in a serial C++ manner?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm working on that. What I'm suggesting is that taking the absolute values and storing the sign bits is premature. (+ I'm implicitly suggesting that it's an improvement over the last comparison)

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are discrete, and properly spaced, and drawing from a limited subset, there are other possibilities.

If you're guaranteed that a, b, and c are integers for instance, then you can multiply the vector by itself to get an odd power and then dot it with <1, 1, 1>.  If we multiply it by itself 4 times, for instance, it will give you < a^5, b^5, c^5 >.  If |a| is the largest and |a|=2, then we know that b and c will be 1 or 0, so the value of a^3 will dominate and the dot product will have its sign.  For instance, if X= < a=-2, b=1, c=0 > , then X^5 = <-32, 1, 0>.  When you dot this with <1, 1, 1> you get -31, whose sign reflects that of the largest absolute value.  As the absolute value of the largest number increases, the disparity between it and the other terms will tend to converge - for instance, if we have <-8, 7, 7>, then the algorithm above gives X^5=<-32768, 16807, 16807>, you dot that with <1, 1, 1> and get 846, so the algorithm fails with exponent 5.  If we bump the exponent up to 7, we get <-2097152, 823543, 823543>, dotted with <1, 1, 1> gives us -450066, which is the correct answer.  Eventually round-off errors will also break this method.  But I'm hoping it might give some insights into other alternatives, if you know the limits on your dataset.

As a footnote, remember that X^5 = (X*X) * (X*X) * X, so you do one multiply to get X^2, multiply that by itself to get X^4, and then multiply by X - three multiplies total.  You need an odd exponent to preserve sign.